# An operation is already in progress - run new task with new contexts

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I execute some work with database in different threads. But I get exception. 
Project on ASP.NET Core MVC 1.0, ef core, postgres 9.5.
I have made example when I create new Context for every task - new NpgsqlConnection.

```
private void TestNewContext(long[] checkedEvents, User user)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    int stepCount = 700;
    for (int i = 0; i < checkedEvents.Length; i += stepCount)
    {
        int lenght = checkedEvents.Length >= i + stepCount ? stepCount : checkedEvents.Length - i;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Current part from " + i + " to " + lenght, "Dumi");
        long[] part = new long[lenght];
        Array.Copy(checkedEvents, i, part, 0, lenght);

        var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
                    .BuildServiceProvider();

            var builder = new Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataLayer.Context.MicroContext>()
                .UseNpgsql(new Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection("User ID=postgres;Password=12345678;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=bar;Pooling=true;Application Name=bar;"))
                .UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);

            using (DataLayer.Context.MicroContext context = new DataLayer.Context.MicroContext(builder.Options))
            {
                var dumiEvents = context.DumiEvents.Where(x => checkedEvents.Contains(x.Id) && x.DumiStateId == DumiState.NotTreated.Id);

                foreach (var dumiEvent in dumiEvents)
                {                            
                    ImportResult importResult = 
                        context.ImportResults.FirstOrDefault(j => j.Id == dumiEvent.ImportResultId);// exception here
                }
            }
        });
        tasks.Add(task);
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

**As result a get:**
An operation is already in progress.

**Stack:**

```
   в Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.StartUserAction(ConnectorState newState)
   в Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior)
   в Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, String executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, Boolean openConnection, Boolean closeConnection)
   в Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, Boolean manageConnection)
   в Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   в Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_ShapedQuery>d__3`1.MoveNext()
   в System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   в lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )
   в Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass19_1`1.<CompileQuery>b__1(QueryContext qc)
   в Xrm.Micro.Controllers.DumiImportController.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<TestNewContext>b__0() в C:\Users\Albert\micro\Xrm.Micro\Xrm.Micro\Controllers\DumiImportController.cs:строка 193
   в System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

**Project.json**

Comment: Yeah this is because the foreach on the dumiEvents will keep the query open until it has gone through all the dumiEvents. And then you start a new query when you get the importResult. And you can not run two queries at the same time.

To load all the dumiEvents first before you start the second query you can change:
var dumiEvents = context.DumiEvents.Where(x => checkedEvents.Contains(x.Id) && x.DumiStateId == DumiState.NotTreated.Id)
to
var dumiEvents = context.DumiEvents.Where(x => checkedEvents.Contains(x.Id) && x.DumiStateId == DumiState.NotTreated.Id).ToList()

Comment: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/826